# MySQL UNIQUE for 2 columns and index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ta
(
    id                  BIGINT      NOT NULL auto_increment,
    company_id          BIGINT      NOT NULL,
    language            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    created_at          DATETIME,
    modified_at         DATETIME,
    version             BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_ta (company_id, language)
) engine = InnoDB;


CREATE INDEX ta_company_id on `ta` (company_id);
```

My question is if I need this line:

```
CREATE INDEX ta_company_id on `ta` (company_id);
```

?

Does `UNIQUE` create indexes on `company_id, language` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* don't need the extra index on `company_id`.

The UNIQUE KEY creates an index on the pair of columns (`company_id`, `language`) in that order. So any query you would run searching for a specific value of `company_id` would be able to use that index, even though it only references the first column of the unique key index.

You can see this in EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ta WHERE company_id = 1234;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ta    | NULL       | ref  | unique_ta     | unique_ta | 8       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

You can see `key_len: 8` meaning it is using 8 bytes of the index, and the first BIGINT for company_id is 8 bytes.

Whereas searching for both columns will use the full 50-byte size of the index (8 bytes for the BIGINT + 10 characters for the VARCHAR, 4 bytes per character using utf8mb4, plus a couple of bytes for the VARCHAR length):

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ta WHERE company_id = 1234 AND language = 'EN';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ta    | NULL       | const | unique_ta     | unique_ta | 50      | const,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
```

I said at the top "probably" because there is an exception case, for a specific form of query:

```
SELECT * FROM ta WHERE company_id = 1234 ORDER BY id;
```

This type of query would need `id` to be the second column of the index, so it could be assured of reading rows in primary key order. All indexes implicitly have the primary key column appended, even if you don't declare it. So your unique key index would really store the columns (`company_id`, `language`, `id`), and the single-column index really stores the columns (`company_id`, `id`). The latter index would optimize the query I show above, sorting by primary key efficiently.